# OS X smbfs Mount Shows Incorrect Permission, Won't Take chmod

Tags: macos, eclipse, smb, chmod

I'm doing development on OS X while my actual code lives on a remote CentOS box that I have mounted as a local share (smbfs).  Some of my files are not marked as writable and need to be toggled when I go to edit them.  In Terminal if I go to any location under my smbfs mount and do a chmod to *anything* it never takes, I have to SSH to the server to toggle perms.  Any ideas as to why this won't take?

Really weird: Using PhpStorm to edit files from this share fails to toggle the permissions to writable on read-only files however Eclipse can toggle them without an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CIFS (SMB) is primarily a Windows protocol and does not support POSIX access permissions unless "Unix extensions" are enabled. Apparently, the `smbfs` filesystem does not support this.

- On Linux, a newer `cifs` filesystem module exists as part of `smbclient`. It support POSIX file permissions, including ACLs. (Probably not on OS X, though.)
- Alternatively, you can use SFTP (`sshfs` through MacFUSE) to access the files.

  SFTP is the SSH file transfer protocol. You already have working SSH, so there's nothing you need to set up server-side.

Comment: SFTP with MacFUSE + MacFusion allowed the chmod.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not what grawity said, it could be a numeric User ID mismatch between the client and the server. What's the numeric user ID of the account you're logging into Mac OS X as (do `id -u`)? What's the numeric user ID of the account on the Cent OS box that you're using when you connect via SMB?

Comment: The IDs did not match.  Updating the CentOS box's user ID to match didn't have any effect though.